# null reference on getArguments

Tags: java, android

I have a `MainActivity` (extends `Activity`) and the a `FooFragment` (extends `Fragment`).

Activity uses `newFooInstance` method to instantiate `FooFragment` and set some arguments to it:

```
public static FooFragment newInstance(String label) {
    FooFragment fooFragment = new FooFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("fooLabel", label);
    fooFragment.setArguments(args);

    return fooFragment;
}
```

Now, inside `FooFragment`s `onCreate` and `onCreateView` I do:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    fooLabel = getArguments().getString("fooLabel"); // null error
}

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_balanse_period, container, false
    );

    TextView fooView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fooLabel);
    fooView.setText(fooLabel);

    return rootView;
}
```

And it produces:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method `java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)` on a null object reference*

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Defining the main activity as:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Then instantiated `fooFragment` as:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    fragments.add(newInstance("bar"));

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and PagerAdapter
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new FooPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
```

Comment: show how you use `newInstance` method. I think that you create it not using this method.

Comment: @h3d0, first of if you want to use Fragment inside activity, you must have to extends the FragmentActivity else AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Added more info according to comments.

Comment: ok, now I need to see how you use your fragments list in `FooPagerAdapter`

Comment: @VladMatvienko your comment moved me towards the answer. Have missed `getItem` refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root of evil.

Inside `FooPagerAdapter` the `getItem` was written wrong.

**Wrong:**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new FooFragment();
}
```

**Correct:**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was talking about. As I said, you don't use fragments, created with `newInstance`. To avoid it, make your Fragment constructor private, and you won't be able to use it anymore.